# Turn an external hard drive into a live usb

Tags: live-usb

So the computer I am working with doesn't have a hard drive nor a CD drive and I intend to boot it from a "live external hard drive" but when I try to format it using UUI (Universal USB Installer) the drop down list doesn't recognize the hard drive as a flash drive. Is there a way to fix this or another software I could use to format my external hard drive?

Comment: Does the system that you are attempting to set up from detect the USB? Can you post the output of fdisk -l Thanks!
Geary

Comment: Well I am trying to set up the hard drive from a computer running windows 8 but it does recognize the external hard drive as a drive.

Comment: All my flash drives are seen as hard drives with my systems. But most of the ISO installers erase the entire drive. Is that what you really want? And with Windows 8 you have UEFI not BIOS, generally better to always boot in UEFI boot mode.

Answer (score 1):

The UUI looks for USB flash drives and there is a diference between USB flash drive and USB HDD. To be able to use your USB HDD as a live HDD, open UUI and ensure that the "Now showing all drives(BE CAREFUL)" check box is checked. Then you should be able to view your USB HDD in the drop down. **Be very careful while using this option because it will list all the drives and you dont want to end up formatting any other drive**

[image: UUI]

*Image source: [PendriveLinux.com](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/)*